# node.js with mongodb using html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

get function of formrouter.js in not getting executed and no error is shown in cmd as i have copied the context of cmd and i have also attached app.js ,formrouter.js,caf.html,plz help me to view caf.html through this forrouter.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var path=require('path');

var router = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var tr= require('./routes/tr');
var fp=require('./routes/fp');
var schools =require('./routes/schools');
//var caf = require('./routes/caf');
var login= require('./routes/login');
var signup=require('./routes/signup');
var formRouter=require('./routes/formrouter');






var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//app.use(express.static());
   

  
app.use('/',router);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/tr',tr);
app.use('/fp',fp);
app.use('/schools',schools);
//app.use('/caf',caf);
app.use('/login',login);
app.use('/signup',signup);
app.use('/forms',formRouter);
//var formRouter = require('./routes/formRouter');
app.engine('.html', require('jade').__express);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var response = require('response');
var forms = require('../models/forms');
var multer = require('multer');
var assert = require('assert');
mongoclient= require('mongodb').mongoclient;
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var http = require('http');

var formRouter = express.Router();
formRouter.use(bodyParser.json());



formRouter.route('/')
.get(function (req, res, next) {

        response.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text;/html"})
        fs.createReadStream("./caf.html").pipe(response);
   });
   




.post(function (req, res, next) {
   forms.create(req.body, function (err, form) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('formcreated!');
        var id = form._id;

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.end('Added the formwith id: ' + id);
    });
})

.delete(function (req, res, next) {
    forms.remove({}, function (err, resp) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(resp);
    });
});

formRouter.route('/:formId')
.get(function (req, res, next) {
    forms.findById(req.params.formId, function (err, form) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(form);
    });
})

.put(function (req, res, next) {
    forms.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.formId, {
        $set: req.body
    }, {
        new: true
    }, function (err, form) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(form);
    });
})

.delete(function (req, res, next) {
    forms.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.formId, function (err, resp) {        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(resp);
    });
});
module.exports = formRouter;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
<center>
  <h1>Common Admission Form</h1>
  </center>
  <form class="form-horizontal" action='/forms', role='form', method='post', enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="finam">Firstname:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="finam" placeholder="Enter firstname">
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="lanam">lastname:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lanam" placeholder="Enter lastname">
      </div>
    </div>
 
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="dat">DOB:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dat" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
 
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="addr">Address:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addr" placeholder="Enter address">
      </div>
    </div>
 
 
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="phn">Phoneno:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phn" placeholder="Enter phoneno">
      </div>
    </div>
 
 
 <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Father</th>
        <th>Mother</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
     <td>
  
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="fnam">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fnam" placeholder="Enter name">
      </div>
    </div>
 </td>
        <td>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="mnam">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mnam" placeholder="Enter name">
      </div>
    </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="fedu">Education:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fedu" placeholder="Enter educationqualification">
      </div>
    </div></td>
        <td>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="medu">Education:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="medu" placeholder="Enter educationqualification">
      </div>
    </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="fphn">Phoneno:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="fphn" placeholder="Enter phoneno">
      </div>
    </div></td>
        <td><div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="mphn">Phoneno:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="mphn" placeholder="Enter phoneno">
      </div>
    </div></td>
      </tr>
   
    </tbody>
  </table>
 
 
 
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

G:\EZY SCHOOLING BACKEND\expresswithmongodb\rest-server>npm start

> rest-server@0.0.0 start G:\EZY SCHOOLING BACKEND\expresswithmongodb\rest-server
>   node ./bin/www

a user made a home page
a user made a tr
a user made a fp
a user made a schools
a user made a login
a user made a signup
a user made a caf
GET /forms - - ms - -
a user made a caf
GET /forms - - ms - -
a user made a caf
GET /forms - - ms - -

Comment: Try this app.set('view engine', 'html'); instead of app.set('view engine', 'jade');

Comment: thankz bt error was different i got it, but still form validation failed is coming